# From an array, lookup a value and it's corresponding key in a text file in PHP

Tags: php, regex, arrays, file-get-contents

I have a sizeable txt file (3.5 MB) structured like so:

```
sweep#1 expanse#1   0.375
loftiness#1 highness#2  0.375
lockstep#1  0.25
laziness#2  0.25
treponema#1 0.25
rhizopodan#1 rhizopod#1 0.25
plumy#3 feathery#3 feathered#1  -0.125
ruffled#2 frilly#1 frilled#1    -0.125
fringed#2   -0.125
inflamed#3  -0.125
inlaid#1    -0.125
```

Each word is followed by a `#`, an integer and then its "score." There are tab breaks in between the word and score. As of right now, the textfile is loaded as a string using `file_get_contents()`.

From an **array of strings** made up of individual, lower-case, character-stripped words, I **need to look up each value, find its corresponding score and add it to a running total**.

I imagine I would need some form of regex to first find the word, continue to the next `\t` and *then* add the integer to a running total. What's the best way of going about this?

Comment: I think you should look at using fgetcsv (in place of file_get_contents()) - http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php and set the delimiter to \t. It may make the process a little easier to deal with each line at a time.

Comment: or better yet, use a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are probably better ways of doing this. But this is so oh-so-simple:

```
<?php

$wordlist = file_get_contents("wordlist.txt");

//string string of invalid chars and make it lowercase
$string = "This is the best sentence ever! Winning!";
$string = strtolower($string);
$string = preg_replace('/[^\w\d_ -]/si', '', $string);
$words = explode(" ", $string);

$lines = explode("\n", $wordlist);
$scores = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $split = preg_split("/(\#|\t)/", $line); //split on # or tab
    $scores[$split[0]] = doubleval(array_pop($split));
    //split[0] (first element) contains the word
    //array_pop (last element) contains score
}

$total = 0;
foreach($words as $word) {
    if (isset($scores[$word])) $total += $scores[$word];
}

echo $total;
?>
```

Comment: @Peter, that code was only to put all the scores into an array for you. I've updated to demonstrate how to add the totals from an array of words. http://codepad.org/gStixDYp

Comment: Great! For whatever reason, however, when I load it with `file_get_contents()` it does not work. When I manually add it to the PHP file, however, it works fine. Ideas?

Comment: Yeah, it's a problem with the characters used to mark EOL. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). Basically, Windows uses "\r\n", Unix uses just "\n", and sometimes it's just "\r". Most GUI code editors can change this. Unix is ideal; Windows should still work. Also, make sure you're using tabs and not spaces, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I wish I had the time to put a bounty on this so I could give you the credit!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to find a word, then it's as simple as:

```
preg_match("/^$word#\d+\t+(\d+\.\d+)/m", $textfile, $match);
$sum += floatval($match[1]);
```

`^` looks for the start of a line in `/m` mode, and `#` and `\t` are literal separators, while `\d+` matches decimals. The result group `[1]` will be your float number.

The `$word` needs escaping (preg_quote) could it potentially contain a `/` forward slash itself. To search multiple words in one go implode them as alternatives list `$word1|$word2|$word3`, add a capture group, and use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) instead.